# Runtime complexity of brute-force for determining balanced binary tree

Tags: binary-tree, time-complexity

I have the following codes for the brute-force method to determine whether a binary tree is balanced or not:

```
public boolean IsBalanced(Node root)
{
  if (root == null) return true;
  return Math.abs(maxDepth(root.left) - maxDepth(root.right)) <= 1
  && IsBalanced(root.left)
  && IsBalanced(root.right)
}

public int maxDepth(Node root)
{
  if (root == null) return 0;
  return Math.max(maxDepth(root.left), maxDepth(root.right)) + 1;
}
```

I don't understand why the worst case runtime complexity is O(n^2) when the tree is a skewed tree. What I think is that if the tree is skewed, then the line
    Math.abs(maxDepth(root.left) - maxDepth(root.right)) <= 1
would immediately find that the height of the left subtree of the root is over 1 more than the height of the root's right subtree. Then the time complexity of the skewed tree case should be O(n). What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Which operation are you talking about? Following http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree operations are O(n), O(log n) but tree sort is O(n²)

Comment: People are saying when the tree is skewed, the runtime complexity of the code is O(n^2). I just don't understand why it is O(n^2). My thinking is that if the tree is skewed (to the left, for example), to check the max depth of the root's left and right subtrees only takes O(n). It could be found the max depth of the root's left subtree is n, and the max depth of the right subtree is 0. So the first call of

    Math.abs(maxDepth(root.left) - maxDepth(root.right)) <= 1
will return false, and IsBalanced is returned. So I think when the tree is skewed, the runtime complexity should be O(n).

Answer (score 1):

In the method `IsBalanced(Node root)` for a skewed tree when it first calls

`maxDepth(root.left)` it takes n recursive calls in `maxDepth(root)` now still the

root is not null in `IsBalanced(Node root)` then again it calls

`maxDepth(root.left)` now for n-1 times and so on.so the time complexity is sum of

first n natural numbers i.e O(n^2).